# how can create collection from the controls of two canvas

Tags: wpf

I have created a wpf application ,there are two canvas i would like to store controls of both cancas to one collection so that i can process them without two loop. What is the best method to implement this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ's `Union` operator to pull the two `Canvas.Children` collections together into one:

```
for (UIElement child in canvasOne.Children.Cast<UIElement>()
                                     .Union
                       (canvasTwo.Children.Cast<UIElement>()))
{
    ...
}
```

Note the following:

- The code shown doesn't actually create a new, mutable collection that you can modify; it merely sets up an `IEnumerable<UIElement>` such that you can iterate over both collections' elements in one go. That is, the two existing collections will be accessed, not a new one.
- The `Cast<UIElement>` operator is necessary because `Canvas.Children` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but only `IEnumerable`.
- You need to reference the `System.Core.dll` assembly in your project, and import the `System.Linq` namespace in your code file for this to work.